# Calling NodeJS function from Python without spawning child process

Tags: python, node.js

Is it possible to call a NodeJS function:

```
function someFunc(object) {
  console.log(object);
}
```

with python:

```
someFunc({});
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the nodeJS process already running? because you can't call it if it doesn't already running or executed as child process.

Comment: You could host v8 directly in Python.  Good luck with that.